# how we update data in database in jsp

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

i want to update data in database after fetching data from database.i have tried but it is not work.please help me.thank you

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>connection with database</title>

    </head>
    <%
    String f_name = request.getParameter("f_name");
    out.print(f_name);
       String l_name = request.getParameter("l_name");
       String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
       String cnic = request.getParameter("cnic");
       String date = request.getParameter("date");
       String inst = request.getParameter("inst");
       String dept = request.getParameter("dept");
       String deg = request.getParameter("level");
       String pro = request.getParameter("pro");
       String adm = request.getParameter("admisssion");


       %>


<%!Statement s; %>
<%!ResultSet rs; %>
       <% 
    try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
Statement s=con.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("update info set first_name='"+f_name+"',last_name='"+l_name+"',gender='"+gender+"',cnic='"+cnic+"',date_of_birth='"+date+"',institute='"+inst+"',department='"+dept+"',degree_level='"+deg+"',programe='"+pro+"',year='"+adm+"')");
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
%>
```

this is code but it is not working properly please help me.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't do such things in JSP. Second, use PreparedStatement instead of concatenation. Your code is currently wide open to SQL injection

Comment: Third, what does _it is not working properly_ mean - does it throw any exception (post stack trace)?